# Looking to start developing on Windows Phone

Tags: apps

I know some C++ basics (able to create a simple "game" using SFML library where you should click squares and they respawn back, that kinda level) and have a decent knowledge of web development (html,css,js,php).

My question is how hard would be the learning curve for me? I would like to create a simple app where you can toggle your maximum mobile data speed (2G / 3G / 4G) just with simple switch buttons. Is it even possible to access and modify system settings in the latest Windows Phone version? What should be the code, setup, how the layout works, etc. Point me in the right direction!

Comment: The question is interesting, but I think it should be posted in Stack Overflow. Windows Phone section is for users, not developers of this OS.

Comment: It was not *previously* possible for a (non-jailbroken) app to change such settings directly, no. It may be possible on W10M; I haven't checked. In general, WP / W10M development is very easy (if you don't need to get graphically fancy, or if you do but have a good grasp of either XAML, web UIs, or DirectX), but "change system settings" is exactly the sort of the thing mobile apps (and their frameworks) are not built for. If it's possible at all, it won't be through easy means.